# The content not shown properly in function callback in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2, vue-resource

I've got two problems here. The first is that I can't get the star rendered properly. I can do it if I change the value in the `data()` function but if I want to do it in a function callback way, it doesn't work (see comments below). What's going wrong here? Does it have something to do with Vue's lifecycle?

The second one is that I want to submit the star-rate and the content of the textarea and when I refresh the page, the content should be rendered on the page and replace the `<textarea></textarea>` what can I do?

I want to make a JSFiddle here but I don't know how to make it in Vue's single-file component, really appreciate your help.

```
<div class="order-comment">
  <ul class="list-wrap">
    <li>
      <span class="comment-label">rateA</span>
      <star-rating :data="dimensionA"></star-rating> 
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <h4 class="title">comment</h4>
    <textarea class="content" v-model="content">      
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <mt-button type="primary" class="mt-button">submit</mt-button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import starRating from 'components/starRating'
import dataService from 'services/dataService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      dimensionA: ''  //if I changed the value here the star rendered just fine.
    }
  },
  components: {
    starRating
  },
  methods: {
    getComment (id) {
      return dataService.getOrderCommentList(id).then(data => {
        this.dimensionA = 1
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getComment(1)  // not working
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should data be a `get` method?

Comment: Here'a a basic jsfiddle of using non single file components, which might help you reconstruct your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mjvzbqvv/

Comment: @whatAboutJohn `data()` should be a function inside a component, is that what you meant?

Comment: Since you're doing `this.dimensionA`, I would think the way to access that is `get data() { ... }` and then `this.data.dimensionA`

Comment: Regarding the fact that you know SFC, and don't know how to NOT use SFC, I assume you are using vue-cli, but lack of fundamentals of Vue. I'd suggest you read the official docs and examples before go on. To be honest, vue-cli might not be a good choice for entry-level Vue developers (no offense). You'll probably get stuck if you want to customize the cli config at your own project needs.

Comment: @whatAboutJohn Obviously you don't know how Vue works on the inside.

Comment: @Leo thanks for the advice. I've read the official docs for a few times, but still often get confused when writing code. The project I'm participating is using SFC so.. Anyway I guess I should write more demos less ambitious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems is scope of `this` is not correct in your `getComment` method, you need changes like following:

```
methods: {
  getComment (id) {
    var self = this;
    dataService.getOrderCommentList(id).then(data => {
     self.dimensionA = 1
    })
  }
},
```

---

As you want to replace the `<textarea>` and render the content if present, you can use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) for this, if content if available- show content else show `<textarea>`

```
  <div>
    <h4 class="title">comment</h4>
    <span v-if="content> {{content}} </span>
    <textarea v-else class="content" v-model="content">      
    </textarea>
  </div>
```

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fbwejLrL/5/).

---

one more problem I have observed in your code is you are using dynamic props, but you have assigned the prop initially to the data variable `value` in `star-rating` component, but you are not checking future changes in the prop. One way to solve this, assuming you have some other usage of `value` variable is putting following [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers):

```
watch:{
   data: function(newVal){
      this.value = newVal
   }
}
```

see updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbwejLrL/20/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've store the this value in the code but it doesn't work. I've tried to create a JSFiddle thanks to @craig_h to make things more clear, but I can't get it work as it has imported dataService to post a request which is undefined here. Can I mock something like the dataService here which send me back a successful response to get the result and then the JSFiddle would work?

Comment: @JonX See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbwejLrL/5/) with changes, also updated in answer.

Comment: thanks@saurabh. The problems still exists cause the data returned in the `data()` function didn't change though works well when print it in a moustache way. See the updated fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/fbwejLrL/19/