# Populate Vue instance data via json_encode from HTML

Tags: php, json, vue.js

I'm migrating a super simple `AngularJS` application into `Vue 2` as a learning exercise and have hit a wall when trying to migrate some code that currently resides in a `ngInit`

I have a `PHP` backend that passes an object to the view, which was effectively handled like

```
<div ng-init="user = <?php echo json_encode($user); ?>"
```

This would set the `$scope.user` property to the user object.

I'm now trying to replicate this in Vue.

From what I've read I could do something like:

```
<div :user="<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>"
```

but it was also suggested that `props` like this should be only for immutable data, and as `$user` will change a little, I guess thats the wrong thing to do!

I've currently got the below - which doesn't work, as when inspected via dev-tools it shows user as `undefined`.

So my php template has:

```
<div :setUser="<?php echo json_encode($user); ?>"
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
:setUser="{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Lily&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;lily@selesti.com&quot;,&quot;wants_food&quot;:0,&quot;food_id&quot;:null,&quot;food&quot;:null}"
```

My javascript has:

```
window.App = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    props: ['setUser'],

    data: {
        user: null
    },

    mounted() {
        this.user = this.setUser; // also tried JSON.parse(this.setUser);
    }
}
```

However as mentioned, whenever inspected, `user` is always `undefined`, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

In case you want a Fiddle, here is one :) https://jsfiddle.net/64yeaek1/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`props` are for passing data to a component and since you are not writing a component you cannot pass any props. There is no built in method (as far as I can tell) for you to initilise from the `HTML`, instead you should use an `ajax call` from inside the [created lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) to retrieve your data. Vue already has a nice package to handle this: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

If you really want to `init` from the HTML it's possible to write your own [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html):

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
})
```

Then use it like so:

```
<div v-init:user="{name: 'fooBar'}">
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk7a2ba0/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding the component info - didn't know that. But would prefer to go down the suggested directive route as not up for over engineering an ajax call just to return a users name and basic meta data, purely for display reasons. The application isn't complicated enough to warrant the extra http oveheads :( considering it already has the data in the view

Comment: If it's for display purposes, then you could probably use a `component` instead, which is Vue's preferred method, but it does entirely depend on what you are doing and what you are using the data for, here's an example with a component: https://jsfiddle.net/hk7a2ba0/1/

Comment: Well it does a little more than that, so using a custom directive leaves me happy enough if theres no native way to do this without assigning a global var to the data definition. Not overly fond of using JS generated templates tbh - our team does lots of digital marking/search so having solutions which work well with our toolset like google tag manager (it cant handle fancy js templates to target things) so less DOM magic the better :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing `setUser` in your parent and want to get the changed `setUser` in the data variable, you have to put a watcher on `setUser`, and set your data variable in the [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), something like following:

```
window.App = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    props: ['setUser'],

    data: {
        user: null
    },

    mounted() {
        this.user = this.setUser; // also tried JSON.parse(this.setUser);
    },
    watch: {
      setUser: function(newVal) {
        this.user = newVal
      }
    } 
}
```

You can have to a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41347418/1610034) as well.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm "Changing" anything, I want to set it on load to that 1 thing it wont ever change for the user. I also don't have any concept of a parent - I guess what I'm doing is just trying to set a default value for a property based off some JSON content in a html attribute

Comment: @Owen Possible to create a fiddle?